# Ban module, Discord bot error.. discord.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, discord.js

1 day ago i publish an issue with for a discord bot that said that my id was not a property of null. Now its works. But it still not able to ban, and it gives me the error marked on the code: `message.reply("I was unable to ban the member :(");`

---

This is the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();



module.exports = {
   name: 'ban',
   description: "ban peoples ;D",
   execute(message, args, client) {
       if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS") ||
           !message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You don't have a permissions to do this, maybe later ;) ");

       const user = message.mentions.users.first();
       const member = message.guild.member(user);
       

       if (!user) return message.channel.send("Please mention the user to make this action");

       if (user.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send("You can't ban yourself, I tried :(");


       member.ban(() => {
           message.channel.send('Successfully banned **${user.tag}**');
       }).catch(err => {
           message.reply("I was unable to ban the member :(");
       })
   }
}
```

i checked to see if the bot needs permissions, i gave it him but it still not working.

Comment: In your catch block, write `console.log(err)` to better diagnose the problem.

Comment: at ``` }).catch(err => {``` ?

Comment: Yes. `catch(err => { console.log(err)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here

```
member.ban(() => {
    message.channel.send('Successfully banned **${user.tag}**');
}).catch(err => {
    message.reply("I was unable to ban the member :(");
})
```

You are passing an entire function into the ban method

Really you should be calling the function then using `.then(() => {})` to handle the promise

It should look like this

```
member.ban()
    .then(() => {
        message.channel.send('Successfully banned **${user.tag}**');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        message.reply("I was unable to ban the member :(");
        console.error(err);
    });
```